# Angularjs Events group by month Filter

Tags: angularjs

**I want to achieve something like this :**
[image]

**This is what I have so far:** 
[image]

You can see in my case the month is repeating. I want to have the months Group by.

Here is my controller code for `getlist`:

```
   Event.getList().then(function(data){
        $scope.events = data.events;
        $rootScope.events = data.events;
    });
```

Comment: What's the structure of `data.events` when it comes back from your server?

Comment: @MatthewCawley Here it is : http://take.ms/X4GZq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For live** https://plnkr.co/edit/jUhSXJJEAqKnJz1H3kiv?p=preview
**HTML :**

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="(key,x) in groupevent">
      {{key|date:'MMMM yyyy'}}
      <li ng-repeat="y in x |orderBy:'start_date'">
        <span>{{y|json}}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.event = [
    {id:'1',ex:true,end_date:'2017-08-31',start_date:'2017-08-29'},
    {id:'15',ex:true,end_date:'2017-05-18',start_date:'2017-05-15'},
    {id:'18',ex:true,end_date:'2017-06-12',start_date:'2017-06-09'},
    {id:'51',ex:true,end_date:'2017-08-01',start_date:'2017-08-01'},
  ];
  angular.forEach($scope.event,function(value,key){
    value.groupdate = value.start_date.substring(0,7)+'-01';
  });
  $scope.event = _.orderBy($scope.event, ['start_date'], ['asc'])
   $scope.groupevent = _.groupBy($scope.event,'groupdate');
 });
```